# Replace text in Linux terminal without using backspace

Tags: c++, linux, io, fortran

I am interested in writing a program (Fortran, C++, doesn't matter really) which uses the terminal as output possibly even for graphs and charts. If I display text, how can I go back and replace ONLY one letter without backspacing the entire section and then rewriting it all? This creates a flashing effect and I'm wondering if there is a way to select characters to change without erasing and rewriting more than necessary.

Is this language dependent? If so, can someone please point me in the right direction for Fortran and C++?

Comment: Look for `ncurses` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ architecture is setup for input and output streams. To control the display properly, you would likely want to use NCURSES.

You can do this to change one char:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 37;

    initscr(); // Start ncurses' main windows (invisible)
    noecho(); // Do not show text typed in with the keyboard
    printw("Hello Gourld!\nI am %d years old today.\n", i);
    refresh(); // Display what you print 
    getch(); // Wait for key press.

    move(0, 6); // Move to y=0; x=6;
    addch('w'); // Change character to 'w'
    refresh(); // Display change
    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get the idea of using a library, but having never used it, your code makes no sense. Could you possibly write a very short proof of concept c++ code?

Comment: @Laurbert515 I think the short sample is pretty self explanatory!

Comment: @Laurbert515,  No proof of concept required.  [Ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) has been around for decades.  You just need to do a little web searching and you will come up code samples galore.  It's basically that or bite the bullet and go with a full blown GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to read more about it then. I was simply not clear about what types `y` and `x` are or `ch`. I'm guessing `ch` is a character, but other than that don't know.

Comment: @Laurbert515 The printw command is similar to printf, only that it prints to an NCURSES window. move + addch replace the character.